# mysqld out of memory: Kill process

Tags: server, mysql, crash, process

I did read and followed these 2 posts:

- [MySQL out of memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745899/mysql-out-of-memory)
- [Optimising MySQL settings - mysqld running out of memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422037/optimising-mysql-settings-mysqld-running-out-of-memory)

but I still get this error:

```
Jun 18 06:06:32 hamid kernel: [42478.128706] Out of memory: Kill process 25316 (mysqld) score 231 or sacrifice child
Jun 18 06:06:32 hamid kernel: [42478.136353] Killed process 25316 (mysqld) total-vm:1354312kB, anon-rss:291300kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Jun 18 06:06:32 hamid kernel: [42478.212879] oom_reaper: reaped process 25316 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

I have 1GB RAM VPS (running WooCommerce site by Virtualmin) and I’m not sure if it’s enough memory.

MySQL config:

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
performance_schema = off

bind-address = 127.0.0.1

key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

query_cache_limit   = 2M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
default-storage-engine = InnoDB

innodb_buffer_pool_size= 250M
```

and did run mysqltuner , give this :

```
-------- Recommendations -------------------------------------------------------                                                  --------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 2M, or use smaller result sets)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group should be equal to 1/4 of buffer pool size (=128M) if possible.
```

In Virtualmin resource usage, before the crash happens my CPU and swap are 100%, and RAM is 50%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I monitor the memory usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9642/how-can-i-monitor-the-memory-usage) 1GB RAM is pretty low value even for a not really busy server. Check your memory usage and [edit] your question to provide details if you find you aren’t exhausting your RAM (but I guess you are…).

Comment: in virualmin resource usage , before crash happen my cpu and swap is 100% , and ram is 50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in virualmin resource usage , before crash happen my cpu and swap is 100% , and ram is 50%

These values definitely mean your RAM value *is* too low.
You should watch the current RAM usage together with swap usage as the OS is swapping *in advance* when there is a *risk* of RAM exhaustion.

[Swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114566/what-is-swap-and-how-large-a-swap-partition-should-i-create) is generally used when RAM is exhausted. Swap is a [(slower) *substitute* of RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Performance) when there is not enough RAM available, so a server should not really use swap. (Its real long-term usage could be something like 1 or 2 %.)

Answer (score 0):

i increased swap size and i think problem solved

Comment: Well, it might prevent hard crashes of your processes but if you added more RAM, the performance would be better. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251464/250300) for details.

Comment: i will upgrade my ram as you advice @Melebius

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ETH Validator on NUC 12th Gen i7 /32GB / m.2 2TB for validator / SSD 500GB for a Windows 11 Pro system and a VM with latest version of Ubuntu by this [guide](https://someresat.medium.com/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-ubuntu-lighthouse-773f5d982e03). Every 24 hours all my validators are down and I'm getting this.

Killed process:

[image: Killed Process]

Comment: This is the second question where I find you have added your own question as the answer. Please do not do this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1291818)